# Would Lalvin's 71B-1122 make a good cyser?

Tags: yeast, mead

From [Lalvin's website](http://www.lalvinyeast.com/71B.asp):

> ...has the ability to metabolize high amounts (20% to 40%) of malic acid.

It also says that it produces "rounder, smoother..." wines. I'm thinking this would be a nice match for an attempt at something with a lot of apple cider in it - like a cyser.

Or do I not understand the implications of malic acid in a finished product?

Comment: I used this for Cyser, mead and spiced mead, can you share how it went ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I pulled out my copy of Ken Schramm's [The Compleat Meadmaker](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0937381802)'s book and referenced his prefered yeast for Cysers... it's D47.  Like you, I've used it in Cysers before and have been quite pleased with the result.  A variation of [this cyser recipe](http://www.homebrewtalk.com/f80/chai-spiced-cyser-71457/) actually won first place in the [mazer's cup](http://www.mazercup.com/) this year using D47.

I typically reserve 71B for my melomels, or anything fruity because of it's ability to metabolize the high level of malic acids from the fruits.  Regardless, I think it would still be able to fine cyser.  You could always add the acid back in if you find it flabby.  Remember, if you are going to use 71B be sure to rack it off the lees.  Brews do not age well on 71B lees.

Comment: Thank you for the recipe! And do you find D47 easily? I have so much trouble to find some!

Comment: You're welcome!  Luckily, I've never had a problem finding it, They stock it in my LHS, and it's at most major online homebrew stores.

Answer (score 1):

Which do you prefer, tart apples like Granny Smiths, or sweeter, mellower apples like Galas? Because of how 71B "rounds and smooths" wines by cutting down on the malic acid in the final product, you'll end up with more of a "Gala" cyser. Keeping more of the malic acid would produce a cyser with a bit more bite to it, more like a Granny Smith. So, it depends on what you're aiming for. Like Atom Kawlness said, though, you can always add some acid back in at the end if it is needed.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of people I know recommend the D47 from Lalvin :
http://www.lalvinyeast.com/D47.asp

I tried once, and I was really impress. I also tried K1 V1116, but the result was less good. But I have to admit that I also change the recipe between those two experiments, so I can't tell that it was only because of the yeast.

Comment: My previous cysers have been made with D47 and I've been mostly happy with them. But I can't help but think that removing some of the malic acid would make it even better. It'd be nice to get that for free from the yeast instead of adding some bacteria to do it after primary.